# Eclipse : MAT error

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-memory, eclipse-memory-analyzer, eclipse-mat

I am developing an android application. In which i am trying to find out the memory leaks using MAT for the first time. I refereed following link.

[Link](http://andmateclipse.blogspot.in/)

Till the step 3 its working. But when i try to run step 4 i am getting error in eclipse. The error log is:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "org.eclipse.mat.ui" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.mat.ui.snapshot.editor.HeapEditor".
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:188)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:274)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.EditorDescriptor.createEditor(EditorDescriptor.java:235)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:318)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPart(CompatibilityPart.java:266)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPart(CompatibilityEditor.java:61)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:304)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:877)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:857)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:119)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:333)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:254)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:102)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:53)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:949)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:633)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1096)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:66)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:41)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4688)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:205)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:80)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:58)
at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:576)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:543)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:605)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:322)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1028)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3120)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$21(WorkbenchPage.java:3042)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$8.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3024)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3020)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2984)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2967)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditorOnFileStore(IDE.java:1132)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.views.DeviceView$HProfHandler.open(DeviceView.java:298)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.views.DeviceView$HProfHandler.access$2(DeviceView.java:261)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.views.DeviceView$HProfHandler$3.run(DeviceView.java:245)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "org.eclipse.mat.ui.editor.MultiPaneEditor.createPartControl(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;)V" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) of the current class, org/eclipse/mat/ui/editor/MultiPaneEditor, and its superclass loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader), have different Class objects for the type /eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;)V used in the signature
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2483)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2793)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:345)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
... 92 more
```

I searched on Google but not getting what is the issue and how to resolve it.

Please give me your valuable suggestion to resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

plugins are interfering, class had already been loaded by some parent class loader from somewhere else, you may have to know which plugins are interfering i guess that what causes the problem.
hope that will give you something to start with and find the source of the problem.

Comment: //Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "org.eclipse.mat.ui.editor.MultiPaneEditor.createPartControl(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;)V" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) of the current class, org/eclipse/mat/ui/editor/MultiPaneEditor, and its superclass loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader), have different Class objects for the type /eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;)V used in the signature